# How to find color of the objects(cloth color of human being)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, object, opencv, colors

I had come across several stack overflow questions and solutions, in all the questions the solution is based on a particular color(red or green or blue). I need to identify the color of objects which are of multiple type. I need to detect color which ranged between 0 to 255. So can anybody help me with a solution based on opencv.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate. What exactly do you want to do? Do you need object detection, or just reading out the color on a specific pixel? Do you want to group objects by color, or just detect areas where the color is as you want?

Comment: What do you mean, color from 0-256 ? Normally colors are represented as RGB triplets, and each component has its own value between 0 and 255. An alternative to RGB is HSV representation, in which H(Hue) varies from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: 1. [Segment your image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) 2. Compute color in each segment. Good luck with that.

Comment: @MatthiasBonora, I need to find out and recognize the cloth color of the person.

Comment: @MSalters, I mean to say detection of any color whose RGB value is between 0-255.

Comment: @Somashekar: Still doesn't make sense. RGB describes a triplet of values, not a single value.

Comment: @MSalters, for eg: 'X' color whose R value is 200, green value is 220, blue value is 210 respectively. i,e (200,220,210). This tells that each R,G,B value for every color fluctuates between 0-255. By combining RGB value we configure a color.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know about what could be the possible color then it very simple. I will talk about one example and you can follow the same procedure for rest.

Lets say that you have several possible combinations, for example a t-shirt could have red and cyan color and you already have an image of such a sample. Then you should do the following:

**Step-1:** Load the template/sample image. Calculate its Hue-histogram (or Hue-Saturation histogram).

**Step-2:** Load the image for which you want to know the color. Calculte the histogram for this image also.

**Step-3:** Perform histogram matching() between all the sample/template/example/possbile image's histogram (i.e. step-1) and the image for which you want to know the color (i.e. step-2).

**Step-4:** For which so ever combination, you get the maximum value...your image has that color. For example, lets say your sample images have an image of red & cyan t-shirt, another image of bule & purple t-shirt and so on. And you get the maximum histogram matching() value for blue& purple , it means that your image for which you want to know have blue and purple color.

Comment: I am not having pre-knowledge about which cloth color comes to picture. It may be any color, but I need to identify and recognize that color.

Comment: your cloth will be of single color or consist of several color? i mean ht

Comment: it may be single or multiple